# linux terminator: configure a command on startup and don't close terminal when the command ends

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, terminator

I'm using terminator con Linux, and I have configure my `~/.config/terminator/config` file to start at specific folders running certain commands

I added a `; bash` (also tried with `; bash && bash || bash`) at the end to prevent the terminal window from closing when the command ends

Some of them, the ones running with `pnpm` (node) works as expected, but others just close the terminal as soon as I `ctrl-C` on it, despite the `; bash`

These work ok:

```
    [[[terminal7]]]
      type = Terminal
      ...
      directory = /home/.../app
      command = "pnpm dev:localhost; bash"
    [[[terminal8]]]
      type = Terminal
      ...
      directory = /home/.../billing
      command = "pnpm dev:localhost; bash"
```

these don't

```
    [[[terminal3]]]
      type = Terminal
      ...
      directory = /home/.../backend
      command = "make teardown && make setup; bash"
    [[[terminal4]]]
      type = Terminal
      ...
      directory = /home/.../backend
      command = "sleep 3 && cargo xtask run --config resources/configuration/dev-opensas.yaml; bash && bash || bash"
```

any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: I don't know Terminator at all, but the support for `&&`, `||` and `;` suggests it uses some shell to execute commands. Then the difference between commands that "work ok" for you and those that "don't" may be because of what this article talks about: [*Proper handling of SIGINT/SIGQUIT*](https://www.cons.org/cracauer/sigint.html). The article sheds some light on why Ctrl+c only sometimes cancels pending commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While typically a noninteractive copy of bash will exit when it receives the SIGINT signal sent with ctrl+c, you can use the `trap` command to prevent this:

```
command = "trap : SIGINT; make teardown && make setup; trap - SIGINT; exec bash"
```

The `:` command used above is a synonym for `true` (conventionally used when it's intended to act as a noop). Thus, we're telling the parent shell to effectively ignore SIGINT while it's running `make teardown && make setup`, then putting the handling of that signal back to defaults before we run `exec bash` to replace the noninteractive copy of bash with a new one (which, observing itself to be attached to a TTY, should configure itself to be interactive by default).